# GDAL ReadAsArray Landsat-8 tens of thousands value on the pixel value

Tags: python, gdal, geo, landsat

I am a new beginner of Landsat-8 and python. I opened a Landsat-8 tiff file and wanted to read the information of the single file (for example here I use LC08_L1TP_172039_20150509_20170411_01_T1_B4.tif file), but the values turned to reach up to tens of thousands instead of the band ranges they should be (like here they should be in the range of 0.636 to 0.673 um as described in Landsat8DataUsersHandbook), I have no idea why this happen and is there a way to convert the values read from gdal module to the real values?

Thanks

```
import gdal

dataset = gdal.Open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\LC08_L1TP_172039_20150509_20170411_01_T1.tar.gz\\LC08_L1TP_172039_20150509_20170411_01_T1_B4.tif")
dataset.RasterCount
band_4 = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
band_44 = band_4.ReadAsArray()
band_44.max()
Out[95]: 35961
```

Answer (score 0):

The values in the tif's are DN values, and need to be scaled. Check section 5 of the handbook:
https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-8-l8-data-users-handbook-section-5

If you want to get top-of-atmosphere reflectance values, you should look in the MTL textfile what the conversion values are.

They are listed per band like:

```
REFLECTANCE_MULT_BAND_1 = 2.0000E-05
REFLECTANCE_ADD_BAND_1 = -0.100000
etc.
```

Read section 5.2 carefully, and don't forget to correct for the solar angle (if thats what you need).